# Translate pseudo code into C++

Tags: c++, pseudocode

I was given a pseudo code to translate into C++ :

```
    Set a Boolean variable “first” to true.
    While another value has been read successfully
          If first is true
          Set the minimum to the value.
          Set first to false.
          Else if the value is less than the minimum
          Set the minimum to the value.
    Print the minimum
```

And here are my codes :

```
bool first = true;
bool read_value = true;
int value = 0;
int minimum = 0;
cout << "Enter an integer : " ;
cin >> value;
while(cin.hasNextInt())   // error here
{
    cout << "Enter another integer : " ;
    cin >> minimum;
    if( first == true){
        minimum = value;
        first = false;
    }else if ( value < minimum){
        minimum = value;
    }
}
cout << minimum;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

There is error at the hasNextInt there. And I don't really know what the pseudo code wants. Can somebody explain to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `hasNextInt()` function in the standard C++ libraries (and that's why you can't compile). There is one in Java, however!

Comment: @Rauryn You're on the right track, it's just not how you do it. You need `while (cin >> value)`.

Comment: @jrok So what am I supposed to change? The Enter another integer which is in the while loop keep iterating.

Comment: You'll stop the loop when you enter something that can't be interpreted  as an integer - that's when the condition `cin >> value` evaluates to false. You can signal EOF to cin by entering Ctrl+Z (Windows) or Ctrl+D (linux), for example.

Comment: Oh that's what the pseudo code means? The system keep on prompting user to enter integer until there's something which is not integer. Then it will filter out the minimum?

Answer (score 0):

This is closer to code you want:

```
cout << "Enter an integer : " ;
while( cin >> value )
{
    if( first == true){
        minimum = value;
     first = false;
    }else if ( value < minimum){
        minimum = value;
    }
    cout << "Enter another integer : " ;
}
```

Comment: But it doesnt display the minimum. It just keep on iterating

Comment: @Rauryn You need to send the EOF character ctrl-D on linux and I think ctrl-Z on windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360129/the-question-on-while-cin

Answer (score 0):

That is stupid pseudo code. We can do better without some worthless bool...

```
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

for(int val; cin >> val)
{
    if(val < min)
        min = val;
}

cout << "Minimum: " << min << '\n';
```

Comment: There's no choice. I am new to C++. And I've to follow the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rauryn This is homework I presume? The answer is "This is stupid pseudo code, here's a better way..."