# Getting a list of number pairs using while(cin >>x >>y)

Tags: c++, user-input, iostream

I need to get a list of numbers from the user, two by two, terminated by ctrl+d. I tried something like what was asked here: [the question on while (cin >> )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360129/the-question-on-while-cin)

but it only seems to work with strings, I tried a whole bunch of things, but cant get it to work.

For example, the following code accepts one pair of ints, and then ends:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int x,y;
    while (cin >> x >> y) 
    {
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "For example, what is wrong with this:" You need to tell us what's wrong with that code: what you entered, what the code printed, and how it was different from what you expected the code to do.

Comment: When testing it locally, there is no error.

Comment: @BensonLin same here, no error.

Comment: I edited the question. There is no error, but it only takes one pair of numbers.

Comment: do you know what `cin >> x >>y` returns?

Comment: I think it's correct program. what is your problem? what  compiler are you using?