# c++ : splitting a string from user input into vector using spaces

Tags: c++, vector, split

I wrote a program in c++ that should split a string into a vector using spaces.
Right now what the while loop is doing is that it reads the whole strong i put in but it doesn't break out once it is done. 
How do I make it break out of the loop once it is done reading?
p.s: I print the size everytime it ran through the loop and that's how I found out that it went through all the individual numbers in the string

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> postfix;
    double result;
    cout << "Please enter the postfix equation that you want to evaluate     Note: it can not be empty!\n";
    vector<string> expression;
    string token;
    while (cin >> token)
    {
        expression.push_back(token);
        cout <<expression.size()<<endl;
    }

    postfix = expression;
    evaluatePostfix(postfix,result);
    cout <<"End"<<endl;
}
```

This is a sample of what I am currently getting:

```
Please enter the postfix equation that you want to evaluate     Note: it can not
 be empty!
6 9 7 1 2
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to signify no more input for string ss in the loop while (cin >> ss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360129/how-to-signify-no-more-input-for-string-ss-in-the-loop-while-cin-ss)

Answer (score -1):

you need to introduce a character to break the while loop once it is input?