# How to stop while loop `while(cin>>str){ ... }` which taking string as input?

Tags: c++, string, clion, cin, eof

Now these two Question are same to mine and Answers to them is For *windows* `ctrl-z` for *Unix* `ctrl-D`. But they don't work on my Clion IDE, So I am asking this Question.

[c++ when will while(cin>>s) stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50999994/11862989)

[How to signify no more input for string ss in the loop while (cin >> ss)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5360129/11862989)

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    while(std::cin>>str)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Works fine but I find it's just infinite loop.

Comment: There is some answers on this site that say you may have to press the ctrl-z or ctrl-d more than 1 time. I also found this: [http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/)